# Django Models - Filter third model, based on two connected models?

Tags: django, django-models

How Can StoreDefaultAudience be improved?

John's Store - Audiences: Audience A, Audience B, Audience C

Nicole's Store - Audiences: Audience D, Audience E

for StoreDefaultAudience John's Store should only be able to choose Audience A, Audience B, Audience C as a default audience

for StoreDefaultAudience Nicole's Store should only be able to choose Audience D, Audience E as a default audience

```
class Store(models.Model):
    store_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Audience(models.Model):
    audience_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    store = models.ForeignKey(Store, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

# only one StoreDefaultAudience should be allowed per Store
# the default audiences should only be that stores audiences
class StoreDefaultAudience(models.Model)
    default_audience = models.ForeignKey(Audience, on_delete=models.CASCADE, unique=True)
    store = models.ForeignKey(Store, on_delete=models.CASCADE, unique=True)
```

Comment: #You can limit the choices each user gets on your forms.py by overriding init
#Pass the user's store as argument. It will be used to filter the queryset

class StoreDefaultAudience(forms.ModelForm):

 def __init__(self, store, *args, **kwargs):
  super(StoreDefaultAudience, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  self.fields['default_audience'] = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset = models.Audience.objects.filter(store = store))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `default_audience` of a `StoreDefaultAudience` is only ever the `store`'s default audience, you don't really need to create a column for it in the database, consider using a property shortcut instead:

You can also limit the `ForeignKey` choices using `limit_choices_to` - but keep in mind this really only effects `ModelForm`s such as the one on the admin page.

More: (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.limit_choices_to)

```
class Audience(models.Model):
    
    ...

    # add related name to store field:
    store = models.ForeignKey(Store, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_named='audiences')


class StoreDefaultAudience(models.Model)
    store = models.ForeignKey(..., limit_choices_to=<the query set>)
    @property
    def default_audience(self): return self.store.audiences.all()
```

Comment: I don't think this solves the problem. For example for John's Store, his default Audience can either be Audience A, Audience B, or Audience C. And John's Store should be able to modify which is their default audience.

Comment: Default Audience is not A B and C, Default Audience is A or B or C, you have to pick one.